# linq where any intersect contains

Tags: c#, linq

Soooo... I am writing a tool which task is to collect xmls on servers based on parameters.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
private List<string> GetListXmls(string strPath, List<string> colctNames)
{
    string regexExpr = "\\\\\\\\" + strStager + "\\\\APPLI\\\\" + strEnvir + "\\\\[a-zA-Z]{3}\\\\Bin\\\\";

    if(colctNames == null)
    {
            List<string> xmlColct = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                                    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, regexExpr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) &&
                                                                x.ToLower().Contains("msgtrait") &&
                                                                x.EndsWith(".xml"))
                                                    .ToList();

            return xmlColct;
    }
    else
    {
        List<string> xmlColct = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                                    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, regexExpr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) &&
                                                                x.ToLower().Contains("msgtrait") &&
                                                                x.EndsWith(".xml"))
                                                    .ToList();

        List<string> finalList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string strFich in xmlColct)
        {
            if (colctNames.Any(item => strFich.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower())))
            {
                finalList.Add(strFich);
            }
        }

        return finalList;
        // include some kind of linq method to get only what I want instead of stripping down the list...
    }


}
```

Basically the need is to get any files on a server which match `ABN_msgTrait.xml`. My need is that if the user is seeking only `ORL`, `UQM` or `BLABLABLA`, the method will **get** only the needed list instead of stripping down all the results to what I need. Bear in mind that the list `xmlColct` is a list of paths which may contain the `ORL` name in it like this: `ORL_msgtrait.xml`.

So my question is: is there a way to merge the foreach I'm doing in my linq request to **avoid** having to retrieve all the xmls and then strip the unwanted ones?

Comment: Question is unclear? What do you actually want that isn't there now?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Ooh! Sorry! Will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> xmlColct = Directory.GetFiles(strPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, regexExpr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) &&
        x.ToLower().Contains("msgtrait") &&
        x.EndsWith(".xml") &&
        colctNames.Any(item => x.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower())))
    .ToList();
```

But if you are already using Regex you can add to it that:

1. It ends with ".xml"
2. Contains "msgtrait" at the name area
3. And also the `Any` part with some `string.Join` in order to form the pattern for the optional values of the `colctNames`